# Getting a compiler warning for creating CFArrayRef

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have the following code for some Address Book search:

```
ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreate();
NSString *matchStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
CFStringRef namestr = (CFStringRef)matchStr;
CFArrayRef matched = ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(ab, namestr);
```

The last line gives me the warning: `Initialization from incompatible pointer type`.

Any ideas why?

Comment: I get no such error using that code. I'd guess it's from the context of the statement, so I'd expand your search and see what's above that might be interfering.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? (GCC, LLVM & GCC or LLVM?)

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles fine for me, as it seems to do for Steven. You probably have a warning on code close to that part, which you mistakenly attributed to this last line.

Comment: Nope. That's the only piece of code that is giving me this warning. I have isolated it enough to say so. So I can keep that code in a method by itself, and it will still give me the warning.

Comment: We can't say more unless we give a complete reproduceable example, with code and compiler flags.

Comment: You have the code. How can I provide the compiler flags? Is there a way to do a dump of the build's compiler settings?